# Combine video segments and stream with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp

FFmpeg can save a video stream to disc as video segments with the following command ([source](https://superuser.com/a/1422415/891494))

> ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -reorder_queue_size 8000 -i rtsp://192.168.10.203:554/11 -r 25 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 60 -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_format avi "/vidcam2cont/ffmpeg_capture-%03d.avi"

Is there a way to achieve the reverse of this (using FFmpeg or anything else), where I want to merge the video segments and get a continuous video stream?

Comment: You want to [concatenate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) videos?

Comment: @orde Yes, that's a simpler way to put it. Thanks!